# How I can Join this Array in a fast way?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

How I can Join this Array in a fast way?:

```
Dim NewArray As Array = {"a", "b", "c"}
MsgBox(String.Join(vbNewLine, NewArray)) ' Result: System.String[]
```

the problem is I can't print the content of the array when joining, see the "result" comment on the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is something like this

```
Dim NewArray As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}
MsgBox(String.Join(vbNewLine, NewArray)) ' Result: a b c
```

Or alternatively, use Linq's [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method, which can be used with any non-generic `IEnumerable`, including the `Array` type:

```
Dim NewArray As Array = {"a", "b", "c"}
MsgBox(String.Join(",", NewArray.Cast(Of String))) ' Result: a b c
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need (well, newlines instead spaces but yes)

Comment: @pitoloko yes, it will have new lines between each entry, I just wanted to make the comment on only one line.

Comment: But I need to do it with a Array type as seen in my question, not an array(of string) type

Comment: see here my new question if can help, thanks again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006522/how-to-make-a-generic-function-to-join-arrays

Answer (score 2):

That is the quickest way.  Is there something wrong with it?

Try:

```
Dim NewArray() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry maybe I did not make the good question, the problem is I can't print the content of the array when joining, see the comment line on the code please

Comment: It answrers the question duh.

Comment: +1 VB.Net is not my primary language, but it seems this solution works just as well as mine.