# How to make a generic function to join arrays?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, generics

I want to convert this into a generic function:

```
Dim NewArray As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}
MsgBox(String.Join(vbNewLine, NewArray))
```

This is what I've tried:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim IntArray As Array = {1, 2, 3}       ' Integer array
    Dim StrArray() As String = {"a", "b", "c"} ' String array

    MsgBox(Join_Array(IntArray, vbNewLine, Integer))
    MsgBox(Join_Array(StrArray, vbNewLine, String))

End Sub

Private Function Join_Array(ByVal array As Object, ByVal Separator As String, ByVal array_type As Type)
    Return String.Join(Separator, array.Cast(Of array_type))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also write this:

```
Private Function Join_Array(ByVal array As Array, ByVal Separator As String)
    Return String.Join(Separator, array.Cast(Of Object).Select(Function(x) x.ToString))
End Function

MsgBox(Join_Array(StrArray, " ")) ' a b c
MsgBox(Join_Array(IntArray, " ")) ' 1 2 3
```

Here, you depend on the object's `ToString` method to do any formatting you might need. Note that this is not actually a generic method. Generics are specified at compile time, but in this case, I'm calling the `Integer` class's override of the `ToString` method at run time.

A proper generic function would look like this

```
Private Function Join_Array(Of T)(ByVal array As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal Separator As String)
    Return String.Join(Separator, array.Select(Function(x) x.ToString))
End Function
```

Notice there is no need to call `Cast` since inside the function, since the type is known at compile time. However, because `IntArray` is non-generic, in your `Form1_Load` method you'd have to call it like this:

```
MsgBox(Join_Array(IntArray.Cast(Of Integer), " ")) ' 1 2 3
```